# Searching for special character like # and + using Elastic Search

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I am using standard analyzer in my project but when i want to search jobs based on title with some special character like # or + it does not works and return items contains the requested text.

```
@Data
@Document(indexName = "jobs")
public final class Job {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Long)
    private Long userId;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, analyzer = "standard")
    private String title;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, analyzer = "standard")
    private String description;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private JobStatus status;
}
```

Comment: The standard analyzer will remove the special characters, you need to search for the keyword type field or generate another analyzer to avoid removing the characters.

Answer (score 0):

The [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) uses, [standard tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html). Standard tokenizer uses [Unicode Standard Annex #29](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/) that tokenizes your "text" and removes `+` and `#` in your case.

### What you can do?

1. You can use the `.keyword` field. It won't be analyzed by default.
2. You can create a new field with the [custom analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html).

Details:

```
GET _analyze
{
  "text": ["test+test#test  ### +++"]
}
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "test",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "test",
      "start_offset": 5,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "test",
      "start_offset": 10,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    }
  ]
}
```